# Is it possible to combine cnn and rnn?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to know if it is possible to combine rnn and cnn. I explain you :

I have pictures of bikes, cars and moto and evry pictures is linked to a text. For instance for a car I can have the following text :

"4 wheels"

For a bike I can have that :

"2 wheels"

or

"handlebar"

And I wonder if I can create a convolutionnal neural network for the pictures and a recurrent neural network for the text. Do you know where I can find informations about that ?

Comment: Yes this is a very common theme in current deep learning research, and you'll find plenty of resources about it on google scholar and diverse blogs. However StackOverflow is not the place to ask this question.

Comment: Yes, where you will use CNN to extract features from the input images and the RNN to build the captions for those images. However, I think your output is too simple as you could build a simple linear classifier with the set of classes that you want to clasify.

Comment: Do you know where I can find documentation about that ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions. Non-coding questions about ML & data science methodology are off-topic here, and should be posted at [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead; please notice the intro and **NOTE** in the `deep-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/deep-learning/info).

Answer (score 0):

Yes CNN and RNN can be combined

CNN is applied to Images
RNN is applied to Sequence Models

It is a very common in Deep Learning
**Image Captioning** is one example where both of them are used